# Visual Studio Code file search not tracking project files correctly

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code is showing non-existent files. For example, creating a file with the wrong name

```
doga.txt
```

Then correcting that name

```
dog.txt
```

Will often show `doga.txt` in the file search for days after. Clicking on that file throws an error and it disappears, only to reappear later. Reloading the window does not fix the problem. This is especially painful during git interactive rebasing.

How can I ensure VSC is always showing a correct representation of my files, directories and contents?